# How do I limit fetching associated entities in doctrine by an entity property?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an issue where I would like to use use the first entity I queried to load it's associated one to many entities. The issue I'm having is I would like to limit the query for "$campaignLogs" to "status" == "public"

The example below does not work, but shows what I would like to do. I found out already that you can't use where() on an array collection as it's already equivalently set or processed the query.

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $campaign = $em->getRepository('STLDevRPGBundle:Campaign\Campaign')->findOneByTitle($slug);
    // This is what doesn't work, I have to change the "get" somehow
    // or does this have to be a custom repository function?
    $campaignLogs = $campaign->getCampaignLogs()->where(array("status = 'public'"));
```

Comment: Yes you have to create a custom repository function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an optional parameter to your already existing custom method. Do something like this:

```
public function findOneByTitle($slug, $status = null)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
    $qb->select('c');
       ->where('c.title = :title')
       ->setParameter('title', $slug);
    if ($status !== null) {
        $qb->join('c.campaignLogs', 'l');
        $qb->where('l.status = :status')
           ->setParameter('status', $status);
    }
    return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
}
```